# Subtracting value based on the other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
--work--
day    hours 
 4       8
 5       9
 6       8


 --crew--
employee     day
   2          4
   3          4
   6          4  
   2          5
   3          5
   4          5

--break--
hours    day    employee
  1       4        2
  .5      5        3
```

Here is the sql query i have:

```
 SELECT w.hours, w.hours-b.hours,  c.employee
 FROM work w
 LEFT JOIN crew c ON w.day = c.day
 LEFT JOIN break b ON w.day = b.day
 WHERE w.day = 4
```

this is subtracting 1 hour from every employee

i want the `break.hours` to be subtracted only if that employee has taken a break.
if he hasn't, i simply want `work.hours`.

Comment: you need to join both on day and employee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COALESCE` is all you need.

```
SELECT  a.employee,
        a.day,
        b.hours - COALESCE(c.hours,0) totalHours
FROM    crew a
        INNER JOIN work b
            ON a.day = b.day
        LEFT JOIN `break` c
            ON a.employee = c.employee AND
                a.day = c.day
-- WHERE    b.day = 4
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e30d/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo Link (*with `WHERE` clause*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e30d/3)